# contract validate error : The originEnergyLimit must be > 0 . Tron ide error

Tags: contract, tron

I have trying to deploy contract at tron mainnet by tronide. but getting below error.

contract validate error : The originEnergyLimit must be > 0

TronIde Current Setting
FeeLimit = 400000000,

User Fee Percentage = 100

OriginEnergyLimit  = 1000000.

Please provide solution.

Thanks

Comment: have you found the problem?

Comment: yes , but i don't remember it. You can try to increase FeeLimit Sometimes contract require more Fee than provided Limit , but first try to upload it on testnet before mainnet